# How to get the path of a deleted directory?

Tags: windows, ntfs

I am using C++ to query the NTFS change journal, and it seems to work alright. The only problem is the change journal does not show up any records for directory delete or modified. Because of which, I am unable to get the path for the deleted files in the subdirectories and subfiles under it.

Does anyone have any insight on this topic?

Edit: Can anyone close this topic? I noticed that the files that were under the deleted directory would come up first as deleted, and the directory delete record would come after all that. Which makes sense because the files are deleted first and then the directory. Apologies for my lack of foresight.

Comment: Are you querying the change journal (FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL) or the Master File Table (FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA)?  Is the USN_REASON_FILE_DELETE bit set in ReasonMask?

Comment: Hey Harry, am using  `BOOL fOk = DeviceIoControl(m_hCJ, FSCTL_QUERY_USN_JOURNAL, NULL, 0, 
      pUsnJournalData, sizeof(*pUsnJournalData), &cb, NULL);` But I figured out what the problem was. Can you close this question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not expert enough to answer the question straight up.

However, I suggest you look at

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/NTFSUndelete.aspx (comes with source code)
- testdisk explicitely only lists that it can undelete **files** on ntfs, not directories ([here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk%3a_undelete_file_for_NTFS))
- the ntfsundelete utility in ntfsprogs

It contains the following rather ominous sign, though:

```
if (file->directory) {
    ntfs_log_debug("Found a directory: not recoverable.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

which *does* seem to suggest that indeed only individual files can be tracked after deletion.

Answer (score 0):

By design, the change journal *has to* manage the deletion of an index since it takes at least several filesystem changes:

- marking the index's MFT entry available in the header
- deallocate the index's clusters
- free the MFT entry bitmap(s)

Without knowing how you query the change journal, I would guess that the API is omitting index deletion information.  If you are parsing the journal yourself, then I don't know why it is not there.

I wrote some forensic tools for NTFS from 2002-2004 which do recover the contents of deleted directories.  But it is not easy.  Scanning `$MFT` for a deleted index is straightforward: just look at the status bits.  Unless it has been reused, the directory name and all other information is intact, except the "available" bit.  Finding the directory's path is a simple iterative walk up the parent chain until hitting the root directory.